# Why is my SQL code not fetching data from the database?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a login system that checks whether a user already has an account or not. I have proven that this php file connects to the database and it shows results when I display a `SELECT *`. However, I can't figure out why my SQL code isn't correctly checking the user ID and password.

My goal is to have it check whether user id and password already exist and display "Welcome user_id". What's wrong with my code?

```
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND password = '$password';";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["$user_id"] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>welcome <?php echo "$user_id"; ?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you get as an output and error?

Comment: What result do you get when you run query manually?

Comment: `$row["$user_id"]` => `$row["user_id"]` ... to get the column named `user_id` to retrieve the value. With the `$` at the row index will be looking for a **column name** that has the same value.

Comment: Oh my god. bad typo. It's working now, I set "password" and it's really "user_password". Thank you all for suggesting to break down the basics first, run the Query in the db and see if it shows.